# C++ Finding minimum in vector of structs using custom comparator

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, comparator, priority-queue

I have a vector of structs:

```
struct element_t {
    int val;
    bool visited;
};
```

With a custom comparator:

```
bool cmp(const element_t& lhs, const element_t& rhs)
{
    return ((lhs.val < rhs.val) && (!lhs.visited) && (!rhs.visited));
}
```

Used with:

```
std::vector<element_t> vct_priority(n_elems, {2147483647, 0});
```

In my algorithm, I want to iteratively find the element with the smallest `value` that has not been `visited` yet, work with it, and then "disable" it by setting `visited` to true, so that this element is not found in the next iteration.

```
it = std::min_element(std::begin(vct_priority), std::end(vct_priority), cmp);
indx_smallest = std::distance(std::begin(vct_priority), it);
// do something here
vct_priority[indx_smallest].visited = 1;
```

Normally I would use a priority queue, but as I need to index into this array during the algorithm, I couldn't find a better way.

The problem is, that this approach is fishy. In cases where `vct_priority` looks like this:

```
{1,true}
{0,true}
{1,false}
{0,true}
{2,false}
{2147483647,false}
{2147483647,false}
{0,true}
{1,false}
{0,true}
{2,false}
{2147483647,false}
{1,false}
```

The computed `indx_smallest` is incorrectly 0, instead of 2.

Could you help me find the error, or suggest some better suitable solution?

Comment: I think you need to rethink the comparator. Which should be ordered first: `{ 1, true }` or  `{ 1, false }`? Does `cmp` meet this expectation? `std::cout << std::boolalpha << cmp( { 1, true },  { 1, false }) << ", " << std::boolalpha << cmp( { 1, false },  { 1, true });`

Comment: `cmp` does not implement a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) so it is not valid as a comparison function for `std::min_element`. You should modify it such that every visited element is greater than every non-visited element, and compare `val` is the visited status is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is evident that you need to define the comparison function correctly.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    struct element_t {
        int val;
        bool visited;
    };

    std::vector<element_t> vct_priority =
    {
        { 1, true }, { 0, true }, { 1, false }, { 0, true },
        { 2, false }, { 2147483647, false }, { 2147483647, false },
        { 0, true }, {1, false }, { 0, true }, { 2, false },
        { 2147483647, false }, { 1, false }
    };

    auto less_not_visited = []( const auto &e1, const auto &e2 )
    {
        return ( not e1.visited ) && ( e2.visited or e1.val < e2.val );
    };

    auto min = std::min_element( std::begin( vct_priority ),
        std::end( vct_priority ),
        less_not_visited );

    std::cout << std::distance( std::begin( vct_priority ), min ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
2
```

If you want to define a separate function instead of the lambda expression then it looks like

```
bool less_not_visited( const element_t &e1, const element_t &e2 )
{
    return ( not e1.visited ) && ( e2.visited or e1.val < e2.val );
};
```

Comment: Ahh, I like your comparator, it is more concise than mine :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have tried to write a generic function using  placeholders but MS VC++ does not compile it. I will try to run it at www.godbolt.org now.:)

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator doesn't implement the [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) that `std::min_element()` requires. Namely, it doesn't take into account that the two input elements may have different `visited` states. Since you want to prioritize unvisited structs ahead of visited structs, you need to compare their `val` field only when *both* elements have `visited=false`.  Otherwise, if the left-hand element has `visited=true` and the right-hand element has `visited=false` then you need to prioritize the right-hand element.  But you are not doing that.

However, something to watch out for - `std::min_element()` always returns a non-end iterator if the input range is not empty. So, if all of your elements have been visited, the resulting iterator will have to be to a visited element.  So you will have to account for that, too.

With that said, try this:

```
bool cmp(const element_t& lhs, const element_t& rhs)
{
    if (!lhs.visited && !rhs.visited) return (lhs.val < rhs.val);
    return lhs.visited ? rhs.visited : true;

    /* alternatively:
    return (lhs.visited || rhs.visited)
        ? rhs.visited
        : (lhs.val < rhs.val);
    */

    /* alternatively:
    return (!lhs.visited) && (rhs.visited || lhs.val < rhs.val);
    */
}

...

auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(vct_priority), std::end(vct_priority), cmp);
if (it == std::end(vct_priority)) {
    // vct_priority is empty
}
else if (it->visited) {
    // there are no unvisited items in vct_priority
}
else {
    // use *it element as needed ...
    it->visited = true;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/xqYTCA)

Comment: Alternatively `return std::tie(lhs.visited, lhs.val) < std::tie(rhs.visited, rhs.val);`.

Answer (score 0):

For comparer, using `std::tuple` as projection ensures to respect [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare):

```
bool cmp(const element_t& lhs, const element_t& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.visited, lhs.val) < std::tie(rhs.visited, rhs.val);
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2f9540ca7274a13)